# Twisted and pyapns for Push Notifications error

Tags: python, django, twisted, apple-push-notifications

I was able to send push notifications before using Twisted and pyapns. I had to restart my EC2 instance and I started up my web server and I started up twisted. After the restart, I have been unable to send and receive push notifications, I checked the twisted logs, and this is what I found:

```
2013-02-22 17:50:40+0000 [-] Starting factory <pyapns.server.APNSClientFactory instance at 0x90f9e4c>
2013-02-22 17:50:40+0000 [-] APNSClientFactory startedConnecting
2013-02-22 17:50:40+0000 [Uninitialized] APNSProtocol connectionMade
2013-02-22 17:50:41+0000 [APNSProtocol (TLSMemoryBIOProtocol),client] APNSProtocol connectionLost
2013-02-22 17:50:41+0000 [APNSProtocol (TLSMemoryBIOProtocol),client] APNSClientFactory clientConnectionLost reason=[Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone'>: Connection was closed cleanly.]
2013-02-22 17:50:41+0000 [APNSProtocol (TLSMemoryBIOProtocol),client] <twisted.internet.tcp.Connector instance at 0x9025e4c> will retry in 2 seconds
2013-02-22 17:50:41+0000 [APNSProtocol (TLSMemoryBIOProtocol),client] Stopping factory <pyapns.server.APNSClientFactory instance at 0x90f9e4c>
```

In the logs, the trackback is: Traceback (failure with no frames):

```
<class'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone'>: Connection was closed cleanly.]
```

How can I go about finding a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so I actually figured out what the issue was. Turns out, my application was still sending notifications to Apple's Sandbox Server. Apple will deny any notifications being sent after a certain limit. All I had to do was change the utils.py as noted here: http://highonpython.com/index.php/setting-up-ios-push-notifications-apns-with-pythondjango-through-pyapns/

Instead of 'sandbox' change it to 'production'. It should solve your issue if your push notifications were working before.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your URL is no longer working. Do you have an updated one? Thank you.